# Horizontal Scroll needed

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I have a panel in which I need only the horizontal scroll bar. I have gone through some threads which ask to specifically hide or disable the vertical scroll bar, but this is not working for me. Is there any sure-shot method to achieve the required?

Comment: Winforms, WPF, Silverlight?

Comment: It is a winform application. Just edited.

Comment: can you paste your rendered html output ? In Most cases specifyin g the height of the rendered div and overflow-y:auto works.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your AutoScrollMinSize to the size of the canvas you want:

```
panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(2000, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Panel inherits from ScrollableControl so

```
panel.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = ...
panel.HorizontalScroll.Visible = ...
```

should do it

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.hscrollproperties.aspx